# Laravel unlink doesn't delete the file

Tags: laravel, web

My laravel version = 7.18.0

This is my code :

```
public function deleteUFile(Request $request, $id, $userid) {
    $temp= UFile::where('id_ufile','=',$id)->where('user_id','=',$userid)->first();
    echo($temp->path);
    $temp->delete($temp->path);
    $result = array();
    $result["id"] =1;
    $result["message"] = 'Delete Successfull';
    return json_encode($result);
}

public function delete($link){
    if(file_exists($link)){
        var_dump($link);
        chmod($link, 0644);
        @unlink($link);
    }
    parent::delete();
}
```

Path is my variable that contains the path of the file.

At the database, the data is gone, but at the folder the data is still exists. What is possibly wrong? Please help me

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? For example, what happens if you don't suppress any error thrown by `unlink`?

Comment: use like this  if(file_exists($link)){
        chmod($link, 0644);
        unlink($link);
    }

Comment: @NicoHaase i've tried using unlink (delete the @) and it doesnt work, deleting chmod also doesnt work, var_dump also doesnt bear a fruit.

Comment: @bhucho it doesnt work when i delete the @ or var_dump

Comment: then it is a permissions issue, assuming that $link contains the file path and not the folder  containing the file,``` $path = dirname($link); exec('chmod -R 777 ' . $path); //set 777 permission to the folder containing the file     if(file_exists($link)){  unlink($link); chmod($link, 0644); //you can reset back to permission in the folder if you wish }  ```

Comment: @bhucho still doesnt work :((

Comment: show me what do you get in $link ??

Comment: @bhucho i get nothing :(

Comment: "It does not work" does not sound like you've tried to debug the problem. Have you checked whether `unlink` is called after all? If the file has the proper permissions?

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks, i've already get it :)